# angularjs SyntaxError: missing ; before statement json airprot

Tags: angularjs, json

am use inoic angularjs , i want take information for data flight airport arr and dep . i cant seen information in html and have error in console angularjs SyntaxError: missing ; before statement airport json .

code

```
 (function() {
        var app = angular.module('starter.bgw', []);
        app.controller('myctlr', function($scope, $http) {

                    var service_url = "/airport.json?code=bgw";

                    $http.jsonp(service_url).success(function(data) {
                        $scope.request = data.result.request.page;

                    });

        });
    })();
```

data json

```
{
  "result": {
    "request": {
      "callback": null,
      "code": "BGW",
      "format": "json",
      "limit": 25,
      "page": 1,
      "plugin": null,
      "plugin-setting": {
        "schedule": {
          "mode": null,
          "timestamp": 1473105000
        }
      },
      "token": null
    }
  }
}
```

no information in html show and error SyntaxError: missing ; before statement airprot json

Comment: Do you know what JSONP and what JSON is? Read about it and you will know the answer to your problem.

Comment: it should be `$http.get` instead of `$http.jsonp`, as it seems to be a simple ajax call

Comment: @PankajParkar work thanks . but still get empty page

Comment: @PankajParkar i fixed thanks